# PyQt trigger a button with ctrl+Enter

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qshortcut

I'm trying to make a trigger for the Ok button in my application
The current code I tried was this:

```
self.okPushButton.setShortcut("ctrl+Enter")
```

However, it doesn't work, which kind of makes sense. I tried looking up some key sequences [here](http://ftp.ics.uci.edu/pub/centos0/ics-custom-build/BUILD/PyQt-x11-gpl-4.7.2/doc/html/qkeysequence.html), but, again, a similar issue if I try with the `shift` or `alt` keys.

How can I trigger the OkButton with `ctrl+Enter`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

According to the [docs](http://ftp.ics.uci.edu/pub/centos0/ics-custom-build/BUILD/PyQt-x11-gpl-4.7.2/doc/html/qt.html#Key-enum):

> Qt.Key_Enter  0x01000005  Typically located on the keypad.

That is to say when you set `Enter` we refer to the key that is on the numeric keypad.

But if you want to use the default enter you must use `Return`.

```
self.okPushButton.setShortcut("Ctrl+Return")
# seq = QKeySequence(Qt.CTRL+Qt.Key_Return)
# self.okPushButton.setShortcut(seq)
```

Comment: Thank you very much